# SQL Server FileTable no access to Share

Tags: sql-server, filetable

although I have set all the three checkboxes (Enable Filestream for TSQL, I/O and for remote access) in instance of SQL Server via MMC.exe to true I get the following error when trying to access the Share / FileTable... What could be wrong that prevents me from using the feature? 
Thx[image]

Comment: The obvious - your account has no permission to access either the share or the folder. This has nothing to do with SQL Server, it's just file permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `FileTable`, SQL Server performs authorization checks based on the user's Windows account. The Windows account must have permissions to connect to the SQL instance and database along with permission on the `FileTable`, just like when the table is used directly in T-SQL. These permissions can be assigned directly or via Windows group membership.

```
USE YourFileTableDatabase;
CREATE LOGIN [YourDomain\WindowsUserOrGroup] FROM WINDOWS;
CREATE USER [YourDomain\WindowsUserOrGroup];
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.YourFileTable TO [YourDomain\WindowsUserOrGroup];
```

Your Windows Explorer screenshot looks to be missing both the database directory and `FileTable` directory in the path. Perhaps this is because of insufficient permissions. The full UNC path to a `FileTable` is in the form:

`\\<servername>\<instance-filestream_share_name>\<database-filestream-directory>\<file-table-directory>`