# MS SQL Server 2016, Filestream

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I'm trying to turn on for use filestream in ms sql server. But I have  follow problem. After I enabled option "Allow remote clients to have streaming access to FILESTREAM data" in sql server properties the  ms sql server service  will create share folder only for user NT Authority\Authenticated users, okey. Next step I tried to open that share folder from my domain network but access was denied. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server FileTable no access to Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963709/sql-server-filetable-no-access-to-share)

SQL needs to grant your context access. FILESTREAM location is a place, to grant access a an object is needed (FILE TABLE)
http://assets.red-gate.com/community/books/art-of-ss-filestream.pdf
This resource may be helpful to get the full understanding you need.